# Does every $r$-regular, $r$-edge-connected, bipartite graph contain a Hamiltonian path?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, bipartite-graphs

The following question is similar to [another I recently asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3771285/811940), however, it restricts the graph class further by requiring regularity and edge-connectedness to be equal.

Given a $r$-regular, $r$-edge-connected, bipartite graph with $r \ge 2$, will it always contain a Hamiltonian path?

The [Horton graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horton_graph) shows that such graphs will not always contain a Hamiltonian cycle (i.e., they may not be Hamiltonian), but is it possible to find a Hamiltonian path in them so that they are still traceable? I tried searching for such a path in the Horton graph with a [naive recursive search in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47985349/9548194), but the size of the graph makes it unfeasible.

Comment: Maybe your code might work on the smaller (3-regular, 3-edge-connected, bipartite, non-Hamiltonian) [Georges graph](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=1096)?